# Why is my div background floating in a different location that the text?

Tags: html, css

I have a form where each section has a small header with a light colored background.  However on the third header the background of the header div is floating directly below the seccond header.  The text is in the correct location, but the background color is not.

I have included the code in the following jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/65u5acs2/

And below here:

```
<form id='contactus' action='#' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset='UTF-8'>
    <div id="section-header">
        <center>Apply to work with us:</center>
        </font>
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%;  text-align:center; ">
        <p>
            <label for="position">What position are you interested in?</label>
            <BR>
            <Select style='width:70%;' NAME="position">
                <Option VALUE="15">Select Position</option>
                <Option VALUE="8">Position 1</option>
                <Option VALUE="7">Position 2</option>
            </Select>
        </p>BR>
        <BR>
        <div id="section-header">Contact Information</div>
        <BR>
        <div>
            <div style="width:50%; float:left;  text-align:right; text-align:center;">
                <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
                <BR>
                <input type="text" name="fname" style="width:280px;" />
                <BR>
                <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
                <BR>
                <input type="text" name="lname" style="width:280px;" />
                <BR>
                <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
                <BR>
                <input type="text" name="email" style="width:280px;" />
                <BR>
                <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
                <BR>
                <input type="text" name="phone" style="width:280px;" />
                <BR>
                <label for="cell">Cell Phone Number:</label>
                <BR>
                <input type="text" name="cell" style="width:280px;" />
                <BR>
                <label for="texts">Text Messages:</label>
                <BR>
                <Select NAME="texts">
                    <Option VALUE="Yes">It is ok to contact me by text message.</option>
                    <Option VALUE="No">It is not ok to contact me by text message.</option>
                </Select>
            </div>
            <div style="width:50%; float:left; text-align:right; text-align:center;">
                <label for="street1">Address Street 1:</label>
                <BR>
                <input type="text" name="street1" style="width:280px;" />
                <BR>
                <label for="street2">Address Street 2:</label>
                <BR>
                <input type="text" name="street2" style="width:280px;" />
                <BR>
                <label for="city">City:</label>
                <BR>
                <input type="text" name="city" style="width:280px;" />
                <BR>
                <label for="state">State/Province:</label>
                <BR>
                <input type="text" name="state" style="width:280px;" />
                <BR>
                <label for="zip">Zip/Postal Code:</label>
                <BR>
                <input type="text" name="zip" style="width:280px;" />
                <BR>&nbsp;
                <BR>
                <BR>
                <BR>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="section-header">Professional Background</div>
        <BR>
        <BR>
        <div style="float:left; width:50%; text-align:center">
            <BR>
            <BR>
            <label for="native">Native Language:
                <BR>
            </label>
            <input style="width:70%" type="text" name="native" />
            <BR>
            <label for="education">Education Level:</label>
            <BR>
            <Select style="width:70%" NAME="education">
                <Option VALUE="1">Some High School</option>
                <Option VALUE="2">High School Graduate</option>
                <Option VALUE="3">Some College</option>
                <Option VALUE="4">Assoc Degree</option>
                <Option VALUE="5">Bachelor Degree</option>
                <Option VALUE="6">Master Degree</option>
                <Option VALUE="7">Doctorate</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left; width:50%; text-align:center">
            <BR>
            <BR>
            <label for="lang1">Additional Languages:
                <BR>
            </label>
            <input style="width:70%" type="text" name="lang1" />
            <BR>
            <label for="lang2"></label>
            <input style="width:70%" type="text" name="lang2" />
            <BR>
            <label for="lang3"></label>
            <input style="width:70%" type="text" name="lang3" />
        </div>
        <BR>
        <BR>
        <BR>
```

I am using the following CSS:

```
  #section-header {
      width:100%;
      height:20px;
      background-color:rgb(244, 244, 244);
      color:rgb(58, 55, 108);
      text-align:center;
  }
```

Any idea what is causing this and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would strongly recommend you move your inline styles into your CSS this will promote readability and usability of your styling, allowing you (and others) to more clearly identify the interaction between styling and the root cause of any issues.

Secondly, this is likely due to various floats not correctly being cleared- a quick fix would be to add `overflow:hidden;` to `#section-header`

This will create a new [**block formatting context**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context), causing the items to display in their anticipated places.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65u5acs2/6/)

Comment: Thank you!  I know I need to work on my CSS it would certainly make my life easier.

Comment: You should work on your markup before, there are some important errors. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/28964432/3120193

Answer (score 1):

Add *`<div style="clear:both;"></div>` in Line: 74 to easiest archive.

View [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/65u5acs2/7/).

> **clear:both** - clear property specifies which sides of an element other floating elements are not allowed. 
>     Possible value left, right, both

---

Some minor modification I made then after updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65u5acs2/15/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `display: inline-block;` to your `#section-header` or just go with another `float: left;`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/65u5acs2/9/)**

Each page can have only one element with that ID,whereas the class selector is most often used on several elements. Its not best practice to use ID several times, So changed your ID to class

```
.section-header {
      clear:both; /* added */
      width:100%;
      height:20px;
      background-color:rgb(244, 244, 244);
      color:rgb(58, 55, 108);
      text-align:center;
      display:block; /* added */
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors in your markup. Actually, your markup is very messy, and you should have noticed at least some errors before posting the question.

Use a html validator or a decent editor that will point you basic errors.

**First, you can't have the same** `id` **in the markup :**

```
<div id="section-header">
    <center>Apply to work with us:</center>
    </font>
</div>

<div id="section-header">Contact Information</div>

<div id="section-header">Professional Background</div>
```

You have to replace `id="section-header"` with `class="section-header"` instead, and adapt the CSS styles respectively.

- You didn't close the `<form>` tag
- You have a closing `</font>` tag out of nowhere...

Not the source of your problement but you should better replace :

- `<Option>` with `<option>`
- `<Select>` with `<select>`
- `<BR>` with `<br>`
- The attributes are usually written in lowercase
- please note that the `<center>` tag is deprecated, use css `text-align: center;` instead

As a convention, I suggest you write tag and attributes names in lowercase.